# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to store combination of attributes as raw data into a single column of another Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET Core Web API. I have these models:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Mandate : EntityBase
{
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual TransactionLog TransactionLog { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionLog
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Mandate")]
    public int? MandateId { get; set; }

    public string RawData { get; set; }
    public virtual Mandate Mandate { get; set; }
}
```

**Models: Mandate and TransactionLog**

Mandate has one-to-one relationship with TransactionLog

Mandate Table

- Id
- DueDate
- StartDate
- EndDate

TransactionLog

- MandateId (Key)
- RawData

ViewModel (Dto):

```
public class MandateDto
{
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int? MandateId { get; set; }
    public string? RawData { get; set; }
}
```

EntityMapper:

```
public class EntityMapper
{
    public Mandate FromMandateDtoToMandate(MandateDto mandate)
    {
        return new Mandate
        {
            DueDate = mandate.DueDate,
            StartDate = mandate.StartDate,
            EndDate = mandate.EndDate
        };
    }

    public TransactionLog FromMandateDtoToTransactionLog(MandateDto mandate)
    {
        return new TransactionLog
        {
            RawData = ???,
        };
    }
}
```

MandateService:

```
    public async Task<Mandate> Post(MandateDto mandate)
    {
        var mapper = new EntityMapper();
        var mandate = mapper.FromMandateDtoToMandate(mandate);
        var transaction = mapper.FromMandateDtoToTransactionLog(mandate);

        try
        {
            await _unitOfWork.MandateRepository.Insert(mandate);
            await _unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.Insert(transaction);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

        return mandate;
        return transaction;
    }
```

As explained earlier, Mandate has one-to-one relationship with TransactionLog.
Since both Mandate and TransactionLog Data will be inserted at the same time, I want to automatically insert DueDate,StartDate, EndDate fron Mandate into RawData of TransactionLog as JSON RawData:

```
RawData = ???
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `JsonSerializer.Serialize` method from `System.Text.Json` to do that.

You can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0) for more info

Comment: Should the data type of Raw data still be string?

Comment: Yes because the return type of the method `Serialize` is a string.

Comment: And if you want to get the Json data back as a C# object you can use the `Deserialize` method by passing the `RawData` as a parameter